# O(1) extra space lookup data structure

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering if there was a simple data structure that supports amortized log(n) lookup and insertion like a self balancing binary search tree but with constant memory overhead. (I don't really care about deleting elements).

One idea I had was to store everything in one contiguous block of memory divided into two contiguous blocks: an S part where all elements are sorted, and a U that isn't sorted.

To perform an insertion, we could add an element to U, and if the size of U exceeds log(size of S), then you sort the entire contiguous array (treat both S and U as one contiguous array), so that after the sort everything is in S and U is empty.

To perform lookup run binary search on S and just look through all of U.

However, I am having trouble calculating the amortized insertion time of my algorithm.

Ultimately I would just appreciate some reasonably simple algorithm/datastructure with desired properties, and some guarantee that it runs reasonably fast in amortized time.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a nice data idea you have already. I'm guessing the problem with the amortized insertion cost is that when you insert and have to merge S and U in sorted order, that's at least linear cost? And it happens more often than you'd like? This sounds a bit like the problem you get if you increase the size of an array by a constant amount as you insert elements into it (except the solution of doubling the array size doesn't seem to be applicable here).

Comment: @TooTone When I posted, I didn't really know if my idea was good enough. But reading axel22 's post, I seems like it might not be good enough. Also, I didn't intend on merging in place, because as axel22 pointed out, merging in place is hard. I was just going to sort it in N*log(N).

Comment: I learnt some things from axel22's post. Re merging, as |U| << |S|, then perhaps you could still merge in place if you were prepared to make a temporary copy of U? So you'd start the merge by overwriting the elements of U furthest away from S (and as a result, each time you did a merge, the order of S and U would have to switch). If you have a big enough buffer, you might even have spare space anyway.

Comment: If you haven't already, look extensively into tending to any duplicate / unnecessary / compactable data in your objects. This is usually a better route than trying to design a problem-specific data-structure (although this has probably led to a few data-structure discoveries in the past).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by constant amount of memory overhead you mean that for `N` elements stored in the data-structure the space consumption should be `O(N)`, then any **balanced tree** will do -- in fact, any `n`-ary tree storing the elements in external leaves, where `n > 1` and every external tree contains an element, has this property.

This follows from the fact that any tree graph with `N` nodes has `N - 1` edges.

If by constant amount of memory overhead you mean that for `N` elements the space consumption should be `N + O(1)`, then neither the balanced trees nor the hash tables have this property -- both will use `k * N` memory, where `k > 1` due to extra node pointers in the case of trees and the load factor in the case of hash tables.

I find your approach interesting, but I do not think it will work even if you only sort U, and then merge the two sets in linear time. You would need to do a sort (`O(logN * log(logN))` operations) after every `logN` updates, followed by an `O(n)` merging of S and U (note that so far [nobody actually knows how to do this in linear time](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.5514&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in place, that is, without an extra array).

The amortized insertion time would be `O(n / logN)`. But you could maybe use your approach to achieve something close to `O(√n)` if you allow the size of U to grow to the square root of S.

Comment: Actually I meant don't use more memory than what is required to store my objects. I ask this because I was doing some scientific computing, and my program used just under 8GB. Also, I liked the idea if keeping all my items in a contiguous array.

Comment: I at first misunderstood what you were saying - I edited my answer.

Comment: @axel22 Intuitively I wasn't sure there was a solution to the OP's problem where the contraints of O(1) memory and O(logN) search and insert hold, and I think your answer shows there isn't. One thing to add, if you allow U to grow to square root S, you will get O(√n) for insertion, but then search will decline to O(√n) from O(logN), because U is an unordered array. This might be tackled by relaxing the O(1) memory constraint a little and using a balanced tree just for U. In any case it seems there are trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

Any hashtable will do that. The only tricky part about it is how you resolve conflicts - there are few ways of doing it, the other tricky part is correct hash computing.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: I actually wanted to stay away from hash tables because 1) I presumed I would need the hash table itself to be proportionally larger than my dataset (consequently i would need more than O(1) extra memory) and 2) because writing good hash functions is tricky.

Comment: If you don't want to use hashtables, then the only reasonable thing which remains is balanced tree. As for hashtables - it all depends on technology which you are using. Most of languages support hashtables and include them in libraries, this works for hashfunctions too. If your object is combined from a few other, you can make hash for it to be one of these other like you would do in database fields where some of them may serve as ID and use hash function for this field to be hash function for an object as a whole.

Comment: @Adrian I think you forgot about his requirement for constant memory overhead. That means that adding a pointer to each object isn't allowed. It also means you can't use a hashtable because, as far as I know, no implementation of hashtable actually uses constant extra space. Most of them actually use 1.75 times the space required. If you don't then you'll have a lot of collisions. Since collisions are handled with open addressing or separate chaining it's not clear (to me) that the runtimes would still be guaranteed... nor the memory.